# How to open .sas7bdat in SAS and export to excel?

Tags: excel, sas, export, sas-macro

I am quite new to SAS. I have got a file with file extension  .sas7bdat which contains daily stocks prices and percentage changes. It has almost 2 million line items. I know that I can simply double click the file and open it with SAS 9.4. But, I am looking for codes which I can type in Editor and open this file. Please help me.

After I open this file, I need to export it to excel. Since it has 2 million data, I can not export everything in a single excel tab. So, What I want to do it randomly pick (say 10,000 or 20,000) data and export only this randomly picked data to excel.

My .sas7bdat file is on desktop.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `surveyselect` and specify the number of records you want in your subset the use `proc export`.

In my Example below I create a table of 10 rows and only wanted 5 row in the subset. just change the value in my macro variable from `5` to `100000`

Code:

```
data have;
input value;
datalines;
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
;
run;
%let subset=5;
proc surveyselect data=have
   method=srs n=&subset. out=want;
run;
```

Output:

```
value=1 
value=2 
value=5 
value=6 
value=10
```

Exporting:

```
proc export data=sashelp.class 
   outfile='c:\myfiles\want.csv'
   dbms=csv
   replace;
run;
```

You can also filter on the data you are exporting, dummy example below:

```
proc export data=want (where=(value > 100 or location='X'))
   outfile='c:\myfiles\want.csv'
   dbms=csv
   replace;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ODS`. This will be simpler, but generate a file which will give warning in opening first time

```
libname rd_data "<Your Path to dataset>"

data temp;
  set rd_data.<dataset name>;
  rnd = ranuni(123456);
run;

proc sort data = temp out = temp(drop=rnd);
  by rnd;
run;
**** Remember this is .xls file, not .xlsx
ods html file = <xls file path - full path>;
proc print data = temp(obs=1000);
run;
ods html close;
```

Alternatively, you can use DDE (Dynamic Data Exchange)

Answer (score 0):

First, create a library to point to the location on the file system where the data set resides.  This is a pointer (in C terms) to the directory.

```
libname myData "<path to folder>";
```

From there you can use a random number and a data step to get N random values.  Alternatively, `PROC SURVEYSELECT` can be used, but you might not have it licensed.

```
data temp;
set myData.<Data Set Name>;
__rnd = ranuni(1);
run;

proc sort data=temp ;
by __rnd;
run;

data toOutput;
set temp(obs=10000 drop=__rnd);
run;
```

The last Data Step reads in just the first 10,000 records which you randomized above.

Then you can use `PROC EXPORT` to export the values.

```
proc export data=toOutput outfile="c:\temp\output.xlsx" dbms=xlsx replace;
sheet="MyData";
run;
```

The great thing here is that you can create other sheets in the file with additional exports.

```
proc export data=toOutput outfile="c:\temp\output.xlsx" dbms=xlsx replace;
sheet="MyData2";
run;
```

This would allow you to create multiple samples or even export all the data across multiple sheets.